# Java add header attribute to other node

Tags: java, xml, attributes, document

I would like to extract attribute from my  and duplicate it to all other node of level 1.

My header look like :

```
<header xmlns="aa" xmlns:ds=bb" xmlns:xsi="cc" authenticate="true">
```

When I got my  and new one strat called DataEncryptionInfo who is

```
<DataEncryptionInfo authenticate="true">
```

And I need to have

```
<DataEncryptionInfo xmlns="aa" xmlns:ds="bb" xmlns:xsi="cc" authenticate="true">
```

When I cast it to Element and setAttribute, new attribute are add after the authenticate, does I need to remove it, add news and add my authenticate at the end ?

Comment: order of attributes is irrelevant. why do you need this specific order?

Comment: I need to do it because I got this document (canonized, sha-256, base64 encoded) and need to match with the hash result

Comment: what library do you use for serialization?

Comment: I just use a cast of node to Element.

`((Element) node).removeAttribute("authenticate");
((Element) node).setAttribute("xmlns", "aa");
((Element) node).setAttribute("xmlns:ds", "bb");
((Element) node).setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "cc");
((Element) node).setAttribute("authenticate", "true");`

When I do that, authenticate is at the begining :(

Comment: what do you mean `at the begining`? when you iterate over the attributes in memory? you should not rely on order of items in collections.  perhaps you can say that the hash function takes an sorted list of attributes? then you can have a predictable order of items